# Exporting from AutoCad Map 3D to postgis

Tags: postgis, export, autocad-map

Is it possible to export layers from an autocad project to a postgis database?

I'm new to autocad, so I might be mixing up my conception of a 'layer'. I have a .dwg file that contains a number of autocad layers (not display manager layers) - I understand that autocad layers do not have attributes associated them like I'm use to in GIS formats, however, each layer does have an object data table associated with it (in a 1:1 mapping). I've connected my postgis database, and I've found the 'To FDO Connection' button under the 'Output' tab, but it lists no connected data sources.